# Función SQL pirámide inversa

Tags: mysql, sql, funciones

tengo una función SQL para que al introducir un numero del 1 al 9 me muestre una pirámide inversa desde ese numero hacia tras. Es decir si le pasamos el numero 4 tendría que devolver lo siguiente:

```
4444
333
22
1
```

Pero el sistema se traga bien la función pero al pasarle el numero me salta el error descrito dentro de la función como que el numero introducido no es valido.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS PIRAMIDEINVERSA;

DELIMITER |

CREATE FUNCTION PIRAMIDEINVERSA (resultado TEXT)
RETURNS TEXT

BEGIN

  DECLARE numero INTEGER;
 DECLARE caracteres INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
 DECLARE espacios INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
 DECLARE filas INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

 SET resultado = 'La pirámide inversa del número ';
 SET resultado = CONCAT(resultado,numero,' es:\n\n');

 IF numero > 0 AND numero < 10 THEN
      WHILE numero > 0 DO
           SET espacios = numero - (numero - filas);
           WHILE espacios > 0 DO
                SET resultado = CONCAT(resultado,' ');    
                SET espacios = espacios - 1;
           END WHILE;
           SET caracteres = numero;
           WHILE caracteres > 0 DO
                SET resultado = CONCAT(resultado,numero);
                SET caracteres = caracteres - 1;
           END WHILE;
           SET numero = numero - 1;
           SET filas = filas + 1;
           SET resultado = CONCAT(resultado,'\n');
      END WHILE;
 ELSE
      SET resultado = 'ERROR. Solo se permiten números del 1 al 9';
 END IF;

RETURN(resultado);

END |

DELIMITER ;

SELECT PIRAMIDEINVERSA(9);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es por que el parámetro que recibes es `resultado` de tipo `TEXT` y deberías recibir uno de tipo `INTEGER`como `numero`, ademas en la función, `numero` nunca tiene un valor asignado.

Debería quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE FUNCTION PIRAMIDEINVERSA (numero INTEGER)
RETURNS TEXT

BEGIN

 DECLARE resultado TEXT;
 DECLARE caracteres INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
 DECLARE espacios INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
 DECLARE filas INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

 SET resultado = 'La pirámide inversa del número ';
 SET resultado = CONCAT(resultado,numero,' es:\n\n');

 IF numero > 0 AND numero < 10 THEN
      WHILE numero > 0 DO
           SET espacios = numero - (numero - filas);
           WHILE espacios > 0 DO
                SET resultado = CONCAT(resultado,' ');    
                SET espacios = espacios - 1;
           END WHILE;
           SET caracteres = numero;
           WHILE caracteres > 0 DO
                SET resultado = CONCAT(resultado,numero);
                SET caracteres = caracteres - 1;
           END WHILE;
           SET numero = numero - 1;
           SET filas = filas + 1;
           SET resultado = CONCAT(resultado,'\n');
      END WHILE;
 ELSE
      SET resultado = 'ERROR. Solo se permiten números del 1 al 9';
 END IF;

RETURN(resultado);
END
```

Answer (score 0):

el caso es que he usado este codigo para un ejercicio que me han mandado que tenia que hacer un procedimiento y tengo curiosidad de que habría que hacer para que la pirámide inversa vaya decrementando el valor de los números que se imprimen en cada una de las iteraciones.

Aqui el codigo:

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS P07_PIRAMIDEINVERSA;

DELIMITER |

CREATE PROCEDURE P07_PIRAMIDEINVERSA(IN numero INTEGER,
OUT resultado TEXT)

BEGIN

```
 DECLARE caracteres INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
 DECLARE espacios INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
 DECLARE filas INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

    SET resultado = 'La pirámide inversa del número ';
    SET resultado = CONCAT(resultado,numero,' es:\n\n');

    IF numero > 0 AND numero < 10 THEN
    WHILE numero > 0 DO
       SET espacios = numero - (numero - filas);
       WHILE espacios > 0 DO
            SET resultado = CONCAT(resultado,' ');    
            SET espacios = espacios - 1;
       END WHILE;
       SET caracteres = numero;
       WHILE caracteres > 0 DO
            SET resultado = CONCAT(resultado,numero);
            SET caracteres = caracteres - 1;
       END WHILE;
       SET numero = numero - 1;
       SET filas = filas + 1;
       SET resultado = CONCAT(resultado,'\n');
    END WHILE;
        ELSE
    SET resultado = 'ERROR. Solo se permiten números del 1 al 9';
END IF;
```

END |

DELIMITER ;

Un saludo